# Como fazer jquery parar em um loop

Tags: javascript

Tenho um código do tipo

```
function check() {
    if (!$.isNumeric($('[name=produto_id]').val()) || $('[name=produto_id]').val()<=0) {
      console.log($('[name=produto_id]').val()) ; 
      return setTimeout(check, 1000);
    }

}

function waitForElement(){
    if($('[name=produto_id]').val() =='undefined'){
        console.log('wait');
        setTimeout(waitForElement, 250);   
    }
}

  waitForElement();
  $produto_id = $('[name=produto_id]').val();


      $produto_id = $('[name=produto_id]').val();
        $('[name=produtofabricacaosel]').replaceWith('<select name="produtofabricacaosel" class="w300"> </select>');
                var callback = function(resp) {

                    if (!resp.success) {
                        console.log(resp.msg);
                    }
                    console.log(resp);
                    resp.produtos.forEach(function(row){
                        if(row.titulo != ''){

                            $('[name=produtofabricacaosel]').value =  $produto_id; 
                            if (row.titulo== $produto_id){
                                $('[name=produtofabricacaosel]').append($('<option>', { 
                                    value: row.titulo+'-'+row.id,
                                    text : row.titulo, 
                                    selected : 'selected'
                                }));
                            }else{
                                $('[name=produtofabricacaosel').append($('<option>', { 
                                    value: row.titulo+'-'+row.id,
                                    text : row.titulo, 
                                }));
                            }
                        }               

                    });
                };
        console.log($produto_id)
              $.ajax({
              url: '../index.php/select-admin-produtofabricacao',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                produto_id: $produto_id    
            },
              success: callback, 
              error: function() {
                callback({
                    success: false,
                    //msg: "Consulta inválida"
                });
             }
           });
});
```

gostaria que somente quando $('[name=produto_id]').val(); for diferente de undefined passase por waitForElement porém ele prossegue. Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: Não existe `setTimeoutInterval` em javascript. Do que se trata  problema?

Comment: Na verdade é jquery me expressei errado preciso esperar uma resposta ajax porém não sei de one ela vem para preencher o valor de i para apenas depois realizar a soma.

Comment: Eu sugiro que adapte seu código ao cenário que você precisa, para encontrar uma resposta mais satisfatória. Cliquem em editar, se necessário, e adicione mais detalhes na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que a sua verificação está errada.

Ao invés de conferir

```
  $('...').val() === 'undefined'
```

Você deveria usar

```
 $('...').val() === undefined
```

Ou

```
typeof($('...').val()) === 'undefined')
```

Outra coisa: Tem certeza que você precisa de fazer esse `setTimeout`para "assistir" o valor de `'[name=produto_id]`?

O jQuery conta com o evento `input`que cuida de caputar qualquer mudança ocorrida em um `input`. Você pode fazer assim:

```
$('[name=produto_id]').on('input', function () {
     if ($(this).val()) {
          console.log("aqui tem um valor válido");
      }
})
```

Comment: Não conhecia esse evento ajudou bastante.